# Best way to return an image from AWS S3 directly in controller?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I am doing it, this way for now in my controller.. but it seems slow.

```php
$imageUrl = 'https://'.$bucket.'.s3.'.$region.'.amazonaws.com/'.$key;

return Response::make(file_get_contents($imageUrl));
```

is there a better/faster way?

Comment: `"https://{{$bucket}}.s3.{{$region}}.amazonaws.com/{{$key}}"`
I think using interpolation that would be better solution

Comment: You can use File Storage: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem